# Score to pass PD1 exam. 65% or 68%?

Tags: documentation, platform-developer-1, study-guide

Just saw the training video and there are inconsistencies in the facts given in two places.

Video and study guide has two different minimum scores to pass the test. 
Please clarify.

> Appreciate if the obsolete articles, documentation, videos, etc, etc
>   can be removed and inaccessible to the developer/user community.
>   Thanks.

[image: Help and Traning video]

[image: Study Guide]

Comment: Its `65%`, always refer the [official study guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/platformdeveloperI). Videos aren't updated frequently compared to documentation

Comment: Always aim for 75% as the minimum =p

Comment: @girbot why not aim  % ;)

Answer (score 3):

Its `65%`, always refer the [official study guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/platformdeveloperI). Videos aren't updated frequently compared to the documentation.

In case of confusion, drop a note to `certification@salesforce.com` for a official confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

For the Admin exams you need a 65% to pass the exam, which is 39 out of 60 questions correct. For the Developer, Service Cloud, and Sales Cloud exam you need a 68% to pass the exam, which is 41 out of 60 questions correct.

Comment: Please show where you got the information from - e.g. links to study guides to give the evidence.

Comment: https://www.bluewolf.com/bluewolf-now/how-pass-salesforce-certification-exam-test-day